# FlatList Rerendering Issue

Tags: react-native

I know this has been asked multiple times, but none of the solutions mentioned seem to be working for me.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Fonts, FontSize, Colors } from "../../constants";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  chat: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EDECEA",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
    //justifyContent: "center"
  },
  introText: {
    ...Fonts.bold,
    fontSize: FontSize.s,
    maxWidth: 200,
    lineHeight: 18.5,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 100,
    marginBottom: 100,
    color: "rgba(28, 28, 29, 0.5)"
  },
  smallText: {
    ...Fonts.normal
  },
  servicePackContentContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    shadowColor: "gray",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0.5
    },
    shadowRadius: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "rgba(217, 216, 215, 0.5)"
  },
  serviceTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 22,
    ...Fonts.bold,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: Colors.white
  },
  serviceDescStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
    ...Fonts.bold,
    fontSize: 14,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    color: Colors.white
  }
});

class MyOwnList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formattedData: [],
      data: [
        { id: 0, title: "Option0"},
        { id: 1, title: "Option1"},
        { id: 2, title: "Option2"},
        { id: 3, title: "Option3"},
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "Option4"
        },
        { id: 5, title: "Option5"},
        { id: 6, title: "Option6"},
        { id: 7, title: "Option7"},
        { id: 8, title: "Option8"},
        { id: 9, title: "Option9"}
      ]
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.generateTheList();
  }

  getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  async generateTheList() {
    let len = this.state.data.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      let randomIndex = this.getRandomInt(0, len);
      await this.setState({
        formattedData: [
          ...this.state.formattedData,
          this.state.data[randomIndex]
        ]
      });
    }
  }

  renderServices = item => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.servicePackContentContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.serviceTitleStyle}> {item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.chat}>
        <Text style={styles.introText}>
          Ask for our help and we will answer as soon as possible
          <Text style={styles.smallText}> (English only)</Text>
        </Text>
        <FlatList
          ref={component => {
            this.listView = component;
          }}
          data={this.state.formattedData}
          renderItem={this.renderServices}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyOwnList;
```

Basically, I want to display 4 random options whenever I come to this screen. As setState is async, I added asyn and await to the methods so that when the state changes it is reflected on the screen. This does work but at times I get

> undefined is not an object evaluating('item.title').

Comment: You got two `renderItem`s, did you mean to do that?

Comment: removed the other one.. was trying sometihng

Answer (score 0):

How come you have specified the property renderItem twice for the FlatList?

Looks like you forgot to destruct the argument to renderServices:

```
renderServices = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.servicePackContentContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.serviceTitleStyle}> {item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong syntax. The render item function should be:

```
renderServices = ({index, item}) => {
return (
  <View style={styles.servicePackContentContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.serviceTitleStyle}> {item.title}</Text>
  </View>
);};
```

What you need is access to "item" of flat list row: ( {index, item} )

Comment: Caused by Flat List data source. Please check the random index which you get from "getRandomInt" -> Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min.

Comment: just checked ..it has nothing to do with the random nos. I modified the code to return unique nos everytime still i keep getting the same error

Comment: You have only 10 items in "data". Are you sure you always get the index < 10? If the index > 10, data[index] will be undefined.

Comment: silly me.. i got your point and indeed that was the bug. Thnks